# how to do Ftp polling with Spring integration DSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to create Dynamic ftp inbound adapters for the flow described below

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    channel="ftpChannel" session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    filename-pattern="*.txt" auto-create-local-directory="true"
    delete-remote-files="false" remote-directory="${remotedir}"
    local-directory="/mock/test" auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000">
        <int:transactional synchronization-factory="syncFactory" />
    </int:poller>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

To do this I have created the below flows with SI java dsl that I register using SI dynamic registration as below

```
public void createSubFlows(FtpConfig config) {

    DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    Connection connection = config.getConnection();
    Feed feed = config.getFeed();
    sf.setHost(connection.getHost());
    sf.setPort(connection.getPort());
    sf.setUsername(connection.getUsername());
    sf.setPassword(connection.getPassword());

    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(csf).preserveTimestamp(true)
                    .remoteDirectory(feed.getRemoteDirectory())
                    .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")                   
                    .localDirectory(new File(feed.getLocalDirectory())),
                    e -> e.id("ftpInboundAdapter" + connection.getId()
                            + feed.getId())//
            ).handle(m -> System.out.println(m.getPayload())).get();
    this.flowContext.registration(flow)
    .id("ftp.flow" + connection.getId() + feed.getId()).autoStartup(true)
            .register();
}
```

The same works well but I wanted to also configure a dynamic poller similar to the one in the xml above . Is it possible to do the same with SI Java DSL

UPDATE

Looks like it works though not sure why it doesnt come in the content assist

```
e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(100).maxMessagesPerPoll(1))
```

Comment: wow..it works...thank u

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `e` in the `.from()` doesn't have .poller()`:

```
   from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(csf)
          .preserveTimestamp(true)
                .remoteDirectory(feed.getRemoteDirectory())
                .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")                   
                .localDirectory(new File(feed.getLocalDirectory())),
                e -> e.id("ftpInboundAdapter" + connection.getId()
                        + feed.getId()
              .poller())
```

?

Comment: yup I thought it should but looks like it doesn't for me .

Comment: Ok. What is the version? And how look that lambda if you convert it to class?

Comment: the version is 4.3.8 I think it should as seems is a SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec, hmm seems it is working now not sure why it never came in the content assist :|

Comment: Glad to see you have managed that. Would great to have at least up vote for this the spending time 

Comment: lol did silly issue ... sometimes need not rely on content assists by IDE's